# How to display text and numbers in SFML 2.0

Tags: sfml

I want to display some text and numerical data over my OpenGL scene in SFML 2.0. I've looked at the SFML 1.6 text tutorials [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/graphics-fonts.php). But I can't get the code to work.
There is (as of yet) no text tutorial for 2.0

Comment: SFML 1.6 and 2.0 are very different. I suggest you follow the 2.0 documentation rather than the 1.6 one.

Comment: @ThePlan, SFML 2.0 documentation is still fairly sparse, that's why I put this question and answer here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of the method names have changed in the transition from SFML 1.6 to 2.0. So the 1.6 tutorials will not work without modification.

First you will need to creat a font, you can do this using a .ttf file

```
//create a font
sf::Font font;

// Load it from a file
if (!font.loadFromFile("../sansation.ttf"))
    //find this file in the "pong" example in the SFML examples folder
{
    std::cout << "Error loading font\n" ;
}
```

Inside your render loop, after drawing your scene, you can add this code to render some text and numerical data:

```
//Draw scene
//.........Draw Scene stuff......


//save the openGLstate if using OpenGL
//becase text drawing may well change some OpenGL settings
window.pushGLStates();

static float frameCount=0;
frameCount++;

std::ostringstream ss; //string buffer to convert numbers to string
ss << "Hello World , frame count is: " << frameCount;// put float into string buffer


//set up text properties
sf::Text atext;
atext.setFont(font);
atext.setCharacterSize(20);
atext.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);
atext.setColor(sf::Color::White);
atext.setPosition(0,0);

atext.setString(ss.str()); //ss.str() converts the string buffer into a regular string 

//draw the string
window.draw(atext);

//restore OpenGL setting that were saved earlier
window.popGLStates();
window.display();
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that unlike in 1.6, there isn't a default font in SFML 2.0.